How to restore AA electrical contacts
Failed batteries have corroded a Kwikset battery array

What is the most effective method to remove the corrosion at the spring contact points? A wire brush seems to just move the spring around.

hold the spring with a pair of needle nose pliers and use a small file or emery cloth to clean the contacts.

Is this part of permanently installed equipment in a home? Because otherwise I don't see how this fits the site guidelines.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact It appears to be the battery compartment for a fancy-shmancy Kwikset door lock.

Gatorback, FWIW cleaning these springs would be similar to cleaning other battery holder springs.

Have you tried CLR?

You really don't need to. The only place the rust matters is on the very tip of the springs. Smear some dielectric grease on them to prevent further corrosion, put new cells in, spin them a couple times, and move on with life.

FYI, "battery array" is literally redundant (and I use the term "literally" literally). :)

@isherwood But remember: Much better to charge a battery than be charged with battery.

I disagree that this is a duplicate. corroded ELV electrical contacts are hard to repair reliably when they have lost their surface material (in this case nickel plating)  the obvious solution is to buy the replacement part.  if you absolutley want to diy  this  nickel plated spring steel wires and rivets are bound to be available somewhere. (or you could solder nickel, or nickel plated. contact pads to the ends of the springs)
